# Exclude open post from related posts

Tags: php, wordpress

How to exclude a post that is open from related posts in `single.php`?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$wp_query = null;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'glavna_vijest',
    'numberposts' => 2
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
?>
<h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "open post"? = Comments allowed?

Comment: No I have in single.php other posts or related posts and I don't want to display there post that is open

Comment: I just add this part 'post__not_in'  => array( $post->ID )

Answer (score 1):

You want to know how to *not include the current post in the related posts*.  Correct?

You know the post ID as it's a single post.  That's the current one being displayed.  You can use [`get_the_ID()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/) and store that into a variable called `$current_post_id = get_the_ID();`.

When you run the query for the related posts, use the parameter [`post__not_in`](http://www.billerickson.net/code/wp_query-arguments/) and specify it with the current post ID.

### How to Get the Current Post ID?

When in the `single.php` template, you can use `get_the_ID()`.  Then you can pass that post ID to the relatable content function.

### Code Snippet

Using your code above, you can build a separate function that does the relatable content section like this:

```
/**
 * Build and then render the related posts
 * section of the web page.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 *
 * @param int $current_post_id
 *
 * @return void
 */
function render_related_posts( $current_post_id ) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'glavna_vijest',
        'posts_per_page' => 2,
        'post__not_in'   => array( $current_post_id ),
        'nopaging'       => false,
        // You may want to add a category query too
        // to make it more relatable to the current post
    );

    $related_posts_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( ! $related_posts_query->have_posts() ) {
        return;
    }

    while( $related_posts_query->have_posts() ) {
        $related_posts_query->the_post();

        // do the rendering
    }
}
```

Then you can call that function like this from within the `single.php` template file:

```
render_related_posts( get_the_ID() );
```

You'll want to adjust the code for your specific needs.  And you might want to expand your relatable content to filter it by metadata, category, or whatever to narrow down the potential posts.